# Reading file from Object Storage in IBM DSX

Tags: jupyter

I'm just getting started with DSX. I have two files in my Object Storage that I want to read in my Jupyter notebook:

- Warehousing-data.json
- Warehousing-sales_data- nominal_scenario.json

I have the credentials. Now I need the calling sequence.

Here is what have on my local copy of the notebook.

```
resource_path= "C:\\...\\warehousing\\"
Warehousing_data_json = "Warehousing-data.json"
Warehousing_sales_data_nominal_scenario_json = "Warehousing-sales_data- nominal_scenario.json"

resp = client.execute(input= [
    {'name': Warehousing_data_json, 
     'filename': resource_path + Warehousing_data_json},
    {'name': Warehousing_sales_data_nominal_scenario_json,
     'filename': resource_path + Warehousing_sales_data_nominal_scenario_json}])
    ...
```

What is the equivalent when the files are located in Object Storage?

Answer (score 1):

Found a sample "Load data from different sources" at https://apsportal.ibm.com/exchange/public/entry/view/07db16e78e1722931e27c074ebe343ae
It works.